# Solaris 11 no sound despite finding hardware

Tags: solaris

I'm new to Solaris, less than a week to give an idea how green I am.Smilie Although new to UNIX, I've been running Linux (i.e. OpenSUSE, Ultimate Edition, Arch, and obviously Ubuntu) for many years, so, I decided to put Solaris 11.4 on my 12 core opteron. I had a bit of difficulty with video drivers and got them to work, however, I am completely dumbfounded when it comes to my sound NOT working, how I can fix this problem?